# Complex Derivative with respect to conjugate?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading about complex analysis on my own. I came across this result which is equivalent to Cauchy Riemann equations.

A necessary condition for a complex valued function of complex variable to be differentiable at a point is 
$$\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$$

I am trying to practice through the examples.

**Please have a look and point out the error.**

Note: I will denote $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=f'$

***Problem 1 $f(z)=\bar{z}$***

Solution: $f'=1$ so nowhere differentiable.

***Problem 2 $f(z)=\Re(z)$***

$2 \Re(z)=z+\bar{z}$, so $f'=1/2$. We conclude that function is nowhere differentiable.

***Problem 3, $f(z)=|z|$***

$f= \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$

$f'=\frac{z}{2\sqrt{z\bar{z}}}$. We conclude that function is not differentiable for $z\neq0$.

***Problem 4 $f(z)=|z|^{2}$***

As $|z|^{2}=z\bar{z}$, we get $f'=z$, so function is not differentiable at $z\neq 0$

***Problem 5 $f(z)=\Re(z)^2$***

$f=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}^2=\frac{1}{4}(z^2+\bar{z}^2+2z\bar{z})$
So $f'=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}=\Re(z)$

Now this implies that function is not differentiable at all points $z$ where $\Re(z)\neq0$

**Related Questions**

Since it is just a necessary condition, we can not conclude whether a function is differentiable at the points where $f'=0$. We have to use the definition of differentiability.

I know, form the theory of Cauchy Riemann Equations that if partial derivative exist and is continuous then CR equations become a sufficient condition. How to capture this point in $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$

Comment: Please don't write $f'$ for the (formal) partial derivative ${\partial f\over\partial\bar z}$. It's causing goosepimples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the definition $$
{\partial\over \partial \overline{z}}=\frac12\left({\partial\over \partial x}+i{\partial\over \partial y}\right),
$$
the equation $$
{\partial f\over \partial \overline{z}} = 0 \tag{1}$$ is just a restatement of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so that it has the same requirements for sufficiency.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) it is enough that the real and imaginary parts of $f$ be real-differentiable, so you don't have to assume continuity of the partial derivatives.

I'm not sure I understand the very last sentence of you question, but I would tentatively say that there is no way to capture the sufficient condition in $(1)$ any more than it's possible to capture it in the C-R equations, because $(1)$ is identical to the C-R equations.

Comment: ${\partial\over \partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left({\partial\over \partial x}+i{\partial\over \partial y}\right)$ to agree with a dual frame for $dz$, $d\bar{z}$  however it doesn't change the  conclusion.

Comment: @AlanMuniz I *always* make that mistake.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same doubt as you do. I'll tell you what I've come up with (if it's wrong, please correct me): In my notes, it defines
$$
{\partial\over \partial \overline{z}}=\frac12\left({\partial\over \partial x}+i{\partial\over \partial y}\right),
$$
whenever $f$ is differentiable, i.e. You must have that $f$ is differentiable at a point so that the partial derivative with respect to $\overline{z}$ is well defined and makes sense, at that point.

Then, they prove the equivalence between Cauchy-Riemann eqs. and $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$.

Also the theorem says: $f$ complex differentiable at a point $\iff$ both real and imaginary part of $f$ (considered as real functions of 2 variables), are differentiable at that point (Frechét-differentiable) and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann eqs.

So I would say that $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$ $\;\not\!\!\!\!\implies$ both real and imaginary part of $f$ are differentiable, you would have to calculate that apart.

Comment: Even though, I couldn't come up with an example in which $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$ but it isn't complex differentiable. If anyone knows, please tell me.